# what does it mean to wrap an in place function with a jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am confused about what is happening here:

```
$("a[class='delete']").click(function(e) {
   $( function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({});
   } );
});
```

I see that at first a link element is selected and then when a click event on that link happens a function is executed. That function says to select (I guess because of the $ sign) whatever the output of another function is. Then that next function selects an element with a dialog class and runs the dialog function on it.

Practically what happens is that the html element that has class dialog comes up on the screen as a dialog box. My question is why is the function which selects the dialog box element inside of a selector?

I know when I delete the selector wrapping the function() there is a syntax error (which I don't quite understand) but why not use this code:

```
$("a[class='delete']").click(function(e) {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       });

 });
```

Comment: `$( function() { ... } )` is shorthand for `$(document).ready( function() { ... } )`

Comment: in the first snippet, I don't think you need to wrap the function in the jquery shorthand document ready - by the time the click happens, the document will be ready

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: `$(function() {})` is the shorthand of `$(document).ready(function(){} )`. `$(function(){$("a.delete").click(function(e) {
   $("#dialog").dialog({});
   } );
})` is the better way of writing the above script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a function to `$()` is the same thing as

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* something */ });
```

In your case, it looks like code written by a confused person. There's no reason to set up code as a "ready" handler in response to a "click" event, at least in general. This should be equivalent:

```
$("a[class='delete']").click(function(e) {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({});
});
```